# Xamarin Forms. Публикация приложения в AppStore

Tags: ios, xamarin, распространение

Решил попробовать написать кросс платформенное приложение на Xamarin Forms. С Андроидом не возникло проблем с публикацией в GooglePlay. Но с iOS проблема:

Как все делал:
Так как не было Мака, поднял виртуальную машину, на ней накатил XCode,Visual Studio. Моя машина с VS2017 на Win увидела виртуалку. На [developer app store](https://developer.apple.com)
для приложения создал AppIDs, Профиль распространения.В itunesconnect добавил приложение. Перезашел в VS Win, увидел профиль, собрал сборку, появился ipa файл.
На Mac скачал ApplicationLoader, залогинился, отправил файл ipa, высветилось предупреждение что файл большой (на самом деле он 8 Мб), затем если правильно понял высветилось, то что файл загружен. и что можно зайти в приложение проверить статус проверки или что-то в этом духе...на заходя в itunesconnect я не вижу чтобы были загружены какие либо сборки. Если попытаться еще раз загрузить тот же ipa файл, то появляется ошибка ITMS-4238 “Redundant Binary Upload”. Если правильно понимаю, то данная сборка уже была загружена. Но в itunesConnect вижу такое:
[image: в itunesconnect]

Вопрос:
Я все сделал правильно , нужно подождать?или нужно что-то еще сделать?
Может как то через Xcode можно загрузить IPA файл?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если пропадают загруженные сборки, значит имеются проблемы, которые выявил анализатор. На почту вашего аккаунта должно прийти письмо с описанием проблемы/проблем.

Их необходимо устранить, увеличить номер билда и повторно отправить на проверку.

Comment: Вы совершненно правы. Спасибо. приходило оповещение на мыло